# Adding Pull To Refresh functionality to UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, pull-to-refresh

I have a `UIViewCOntroller`, and i have added 2 `tableviews`, and 3 `textfields` to it. The order of UI view controls are as follows;

1.) tableview - A - present in the first 1/2
2.) textFields 
3.) tableVIew - B

I need to add the `pullTorefresh` functionality to the `B` tableView, How can i do this. I have tried several libraries (`PullToRefresh`, `EGOTableViewPullRefresh`)

Can someone give me sample code which suits my scenario.

Something like this [image](http://tirania.org/shots/Shot-Plateau.png), (the image shows `Sections`, but i have done mine using seperate `Tableviews`, and mine has 3 textfields in between the 2 `tableview`). I need the 2nd `tableview` to have the `PullToRefresh` functionality.

note: Please don't tell me to try `PullToRefresh`, `EGOTableViewPullRefresh` and it doesn't address my scenario. But, if you had tried it and if it works please do help me.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why exactly don't the open source components you mentioned address your use case?

Comment: @robmayoff You are awesome! But, Could anyone tell me how to implement this ?

Answer (score 1):

iOS 6 added new control - pull-to-refresh control available for UITableViewControllers.

add following code in ViewDidLoad-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

   UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];

   [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh)    
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

   [self.tableViewB addSubview:refreshControl];
}

- (void)refresh 
{

    //write your code here

    // for example

    [self.tableViewB reloadData];

}

-(void)stopLoading
{ 

     //after completing your action,stop loading now

     [refreshControl endRefreshing];   

}
```